# GC and FK command in Thales HSM

Tags: hsm

what is the difference between the output of command GC and FK command in Thales HSM. since they both generate the same (clear and encrypted components).

Comment: Apart from indicating whether it is console or host commands, cannot you simply refer to documentation? They quite obviously do not generate the same, even when you stop looking just after the brief function description.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to console commands not host commands.

'GC' command is used to generate completely new random keys and output on console clear and encrypted under LMK.

'FK' command is used to XOR multiple keys generated by 'GC' command and output final key encrypted by LMK.

[image]
[image]